# Install from SVN to Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, installation, packages

I'm still a bit of a freshie on Ubuntu and linux in general, so please bear with me.

I found this package that I would like to implement on my Ubuntu SSH managed server: http://repcached.lab.klab.org/

Is that possible in any way, or does it requres a degree in some to-me-unknown compiling rocket science?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SVN is just source control management, so to install it you will have to get the source code of the software and compile it yourself if a pre-made package does not exist.

You can do this by getting the latest source code from their SVN repository (using `svn checkout`), or by download and unpacking a .tar.gz.

After that, the most common install procedure is to go to the folder with `makefile` and do a `make` and then a `make install` which will compile it, then install it.

However for this particular package it looks like a fair amount of knowledge is required to get it working, so you might want to familiarise yourself with the *nix environment and memcached first.

Comment: You forgot the `./configure` step.

Comment: Hi Dennis, would you tell me about that? Thanks